# Deferencing Void Pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers, null

i'm having troubles trying to deference a void pointer in C.

Well, i make a linked list that have a "Nodo" with a void* info, that's because info will change of type.

```
typedef struct nodo
{
    void *info; //This'll change types, like different structs.
    char label; // S si es un switch, E si es un enemigo
    struct nodo *siguiente;
}tNodo;

typedef struct Lista {
    tNodo *head;
    tNodo *tail;
    tNodo *curr;
    unsigned int listSize;
    unsigned int pos;
}tLista;
```

Here's my struct tEnemigo, this'll be one of the struct that info could take.

```
typedef struct
{
    char(*siguiente_movimiento)(void *,char **,int,int);
    char tipo;
    int maxmov;
    int pasos;
    char direccion;
    int y;
    int x;
}tEnemigo;
```

In this function i just pass void *general to take the info of it

```
char movEnemigos(tLista *listaEnemigos, char **map)
{
void *general;
general = &listaEnemigos->curr->info; //A struct 
siguiente_movimiento(general, map , x, y);
}
```

And here's my problem, i can't give the "info" that is located general, i read something about cast the void pointer, but i failed miserably.

```
char siguiente_movimiento(void *general, char **map, int x, int y)
{
tEnemigo *enemigo;
enemigo = *(tEnemigo *) general ;
}
```

I don't know how to do this, maybe i'm wrong with all my "idea" of the code...hope you guys can give me a hand.

EDIT: THIS IS THE ERROR CODE.

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘tEnemigo’ from type ‘struct tEnemigo      *’
      *(tEnemigo *) general = enemigo;
```

Comment: Succinctly, you can't dereference a `void *`; you need to cast it to the relevant (pointer) type before you dereference it.  In your `siguiente_movimiento()` function, you probably want: `tEnemigo enemigo = *(tEnemigo *)general;` — what you wrote tries to assign a `tEnemigo` to a `tEnemigo *`, which doesn't work well.

Comment: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct tEnemigo *’ from type ‘tEnemigo’
     enemigo = *(tEnemigo *)general;

Comment: @Nameless999: Either the code or the error message is apparently fake. Firstly, the code you posted so far has no such type as `struct tEnemigo`. Yet the error message you quoted explicitly mentions `struct tEnemigo`. Where did it come from? Secondly, the error message says that the assignment is done to type `tEnemigo` from type `struct tEnemigo *`, while in the actual code the assignment is to type `tEnemigo *` from type `tEnemigo`. There's no place in the code you posted that would match the error message. Please, either post the real code or the real error message.

Comment: Moreover, the error message shows the actual assignment: `*(tEnemigo *) general = enemigo`. Where is it in your code??? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: @AndreyT: I'm assuming he is pasting an error from an earlier attempt, but showing us the code from his latest attempt. Hence, the presence of `struct` in the error, but not in the code.

Comment: @dreamlax: Well, the `struct` discrepancy would be a minor one. But the reversed assignment discrepancy is definitely a major one.

Comment: @AndreyT: well, I assumed OP wanted to treat `general` as a `tEnemigo`, since the other way would overwrite whatever was in `general` with an uninitialised `tEnemigo` structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `siguiente_movimiento` function, `enemigo` is a pointer, but you are trying to assign a value to it that is *not* a pointer (because you dereference it with `*`). Your function should look like this:

```
char siguiente_movimiento(void *general, char **map, int x, int y)
{
    tEnemigo enemigo;
    enemigo = *(tEnemigo *) general ;
}
```

Or:

```
char siguiente_movimiento(void *general, char **map, int x, int y)
{
    tEnemigo *enemigo;
    enemigo = (tEnemigo *) general ;
}
```

You currently have a mix of the two.

Comment: The error message posted by the OP clearly shows the problematic assignment as `*(tEnemigo *) general = enemigo`. I don't see how this answer can apply, considering that the problematic assignment is apparently supposed to assign in the *opposite* direction.

Answer (score 0):

The error message gives the game away — you haven't declared a type `struct tEnemigo`.

You have:

```
typedef struct
{
    ...
}tEnemigo;
```

You either need to drop the `struct` when using the type, or you need:

```
typedef struct tEnemigo
{
    ...
} tEnemigo;
```

Both techniques work.  I'd probably add the tag anyway, but I'd definitely write the code in terms of the typedef name (just `tEnemigo`), not `struct tEnemigo`.

And, as a side note, you should aim to avoid `void *` arguments.  One advantage of the `struct tEnemigo` tag is that you can define opaque types by simply saying:

```
struct tEnemigo;   // There is a type struct tEnemigo...

char siguiente_movimiento(struct tEnemigo *enemigo, char **map, int x, int y);
```

Your code that uses `struct tEnemigo` pointers does not need to know about the internals of the structure; only code that needs to look inside the structure needs to know the full type definition.

One reason for avoiding `void *` arguments is that any pointer type can be passed to a function that expects a `void *`.  For example, if you have a `FILE *fp = fopen("something", "r);`, then the compiler cannot diagnose an error in:

```
char c = siguiente_movimiento(fp, map, 1, 3);
```

even though it is clearly a mistake.  With the `struct tEnemigo *` declaration for the function, this mistake becomes a compilation error.

Rule of Thumb: if the `void *` argument only maps to a single type, then the chances are good that the function shouldn't be written with a `void *` argument.  (There are exceptions: for example, if you have a family of functions called by function pointer, you might need a `void *` argument so that a single call can call any of the functions.  Memory allocation functions are another special case.)